# array from String

Tags: php, arrays

I have  two types of input string :

1. string in a line: 
   example:

   $str=`Hello12345Hello12345Hello12345`

2.string with new line `("\n\r")`
example:

```
$str = '
    Hello
    12345
    Hello
    12345
    Hello
    12345'
```

The ways that I use now is:

Option1:

```
if $str one line:
         join("\n\r",str_split($str,5))
   else:
        explode("\n\r",$str)
```

And Try

Option2:

```
preg_match_all('/[^\r\n]{0,5}([\r\n]*)/',$str , $matches);

$arr = $matches[0];
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: Can you describe the expected result a bit better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$str = 'Hello12345Hello12345Hello12345';
$arr = str_split($string, 5);
$str = PHP_EOL . implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str1   = 'Hello12345Hello12345Hello12345';
$array1 = str_split($str1, 5);

$str2   = '
    Hello
    12345
    Hello
    12345
    Hello
    12345';
$array2 = array_filter(array_map(function($v) {
    return trim($v);
}, explode("\n", $str2)));
```